# importing an external c module to python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-3.x, import

I'm trying to run a python code (test.py) which uses an external module written in C (swapped). Here is the directory structure,

```
test.py
setup.py
swapped.so
ext_src/
    c_swapped.c
    c_swapped.h
    swapped.c
```

In order to use the swapped module, I first run setup.py, which is configured as following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.command import build_ext
import numpy as np
import sys

sys.argv[1:] = ['build_ext', '--inplace']

ext_modules = [Extension(
    name="swapped",
    sources=["ext_src/swapped.c", "ext_src/c_swapped.c"],
    language="c", include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
]

setup(
    name = 'RLScore',
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    )
```

And in test.py, swapped is imported as:

```
import swapped
```

So when I run these on python 2.7.6, test.py works just fine, but on python 3.4.5, I get the following error:

```
  import swapped
  File "swapped.pyx", line 2, in init rlscore.utilities.swapped (ext_src/swapped.c:3533)
System error parent module '' not loaded cannot perform relative import
```

I wish to run this code on python 3.4.5, so is there a way that I can make swapped module working?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I installed virtual environment as python=2.7, so it works now. But still, if there is a way to run the package without using virtualenv, I'd like to learn.

Comment: do you also have an `__init__` file?

Comment: @DeanFenster, no I don't have an __init__ file